# Dynamically stretch a table cell across rows to fit its content

Tags: android, html, css

This is for an Android app that prints reports to a ribbon printer (i.e., one with narrow paper.) To format the reports correctly, I need to generate a table with the following layout rules:

1. The table's width, and the width of each column, are static.
2. Every cell's left edge is aligned to the left edge of its column, *except that:*
3. If a cell's content is too wide to fit the cell's minimum width, then the cell takes an entire row of the table, and other cells in that row are pushed down.

Example:

[image: Table where 2nd row's content spans two rows of the table. Cell B1 consumes an entire row, and cells B2 and B3 have been pushed down one row.]

For what it's worth, I expect that if such overflow *does* occur, it will be in either column 1 or (less likely) in the last column.

The solution could use HTML+CSS in a WebView, or an offscreen tree of Android Views. In either case, all I need is to obtain a Bitmap that I can send to the printer. (I know I can do so with a WebView, and I believe I can do so with a tree of Views as well.) However, I don't believe either HTML+CSS **or** any of Android's container widgets offers the layout and sizing strategies that I'm looking for. Does anyone know otherwise?

Comment: css cannot do this nor a table, if css can allow a element to grow (flex, inline-block, float, ..), css is not able to keep alignement on rows and columns on the fly. you'll have to think otherwise or use javascript to sort this out :( .

Comment: @G-Cyr: Thanks; that's what I'd suspected re css. I'm not even sure if it can be done with javascript: How would I detect that a particular cell in a table or grid needs to be resized? (Admittedly, my javascript is pretty rusty, but I've been looking around and haven't come up with anything yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I found that I **can** do this using an offscreen tree of Android widgets.

A high-level description of the solution:

I start with an outer container (say, a `LinearLayout` with orientation set to VERTICAL), whose children initially are all horizontal `LinearLayout`s containing the 'cells' of the table, which initially are all `TextViews`.

I call `draw()` on the outer container. This lays out each of the `TextView`s in the table in their default positions (i.e., as 'cells' within a row within the outer container.) After that initial layout, I do the following:

- Look for the TextViews in each of the rows in the container and call `getLineCount()` on each of them.
- If `getLineCount()` returns a value > 1, then I remove that `TextView` from its row and add it as a child of the outer container -- i.e., making it take up a full row by itself. I also fill its old place in its original row with a `Space` that has the same width that the `TextView` originally had. The `TextView` also needs to be resized to fill its row in the container.
- Finally, if any `TextView`s were moved during this process, I call `draw()` again to get the re-arranged table drawn onto a `Canvas`, from which I can copy the bitmap.

I realize that that's kind of vague. If I can find the time to strip out any proprietary code from the solution, I'll post it here.